# Spring Boot 3 redirection issue in secured POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this single file in my sample Spring application

```java
//skipped imports

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class SpringMvcExampleApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return """
                <form method="post" action="/home/1234">
                    <input type="submit" value="post"/>
                </form>
                """;
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    String homeGet() {
        return "<h1>Hello</h1>";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{id}")
    String homePost(@PathVariable String id) {
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}

@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .csrf(cfg -> cfg.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/home/**").authenticated()
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

I try to have default page - with button which requires user to be logged in, after clicking the button you are redirected to a secured page, if you are not logged in - you should log in and then be redirected.

In Spring Boot parent version 3 - I click to the button, login page shows up (expected), I enter credentials (which is "user" and generated password) and then I get 403 error code.

In Spring Boot parent version 2 - I change `requestMatchers` call to `mvcMatchers` (because I have to) and everything works, I normally get redirected to the secured page.

Please notice the use of path variable, I think this is important as well.

I wonder what's the issue. It looks like a bug, because technically, it's the same code, because `requestMatchers` are replacement to `mvcMatchers`.

Also note that this is a simplified version of what I have in larger project and I tried to simplify the problem as much as I could.

Comment: What URL do you call? Where is your `@EnableWebSecurity`? Why is your class not public?

Comment: `I wonder what's the issue` well show us your full spring security debug logs so we can see what is actually happening under the hood.

Comment: @dur I am calling the default url for sure `/`. I may have added `EnableWebSecurity` annotation, but it's added anyway. Classes are not public because I placed them in the same file, so person who wants to help me can just copy and easily run the app. Note that it's about the spring version.

Comment: *I may have added EnableWebSecurity annotation, but it's added anyway.* I don't see it. You have to add it. Your code cannot work without it.

Comment: My first guess is that your filter chain is never build. To be sure add a log or breakpoint. *I am calling the default url for sure /* Then you shouldn't get login page. This URL is permitted. That's another reason for my guess.

Comment: @dur I mean it's added anyway by Spring. I tried it manually as well and didn't help. What place would be best to add a breakpoint?

Comment: Why do you think that Spring will add it? AFAIK Spring doesn't do that. Your filter chain has only one line, there you should add the breakpoint.

Comment: Once again, where are your debug logs?

Comment: Can you try adding `authorizeHttpRequests().dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()` and tell if it works? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_permit_forward_when_using_spring_mvc

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Nope :( it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fixed in Spring Boot `3.0.3` ; broken in `3.0.0` through `3.0.2`.

EDIT: The fix came in Spring Security `6.0.2`, when [DefaultSavedRequest.doesRequestMatch does not work, when matchingRequestParameterName is set](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12665) was fixed.